# Positive roots of the Tits unit form and dimension vectors

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional quiver algebra such that two indecomposable modules are isomorphic iff their dimension vectors are the same. Let $T_A$ be the tits unit form of $A$ and $r_A$ the set of positive roots of $T_A$ and $L_A$ the set of dimension vectors of indecomposable modules of $A$:

> Question: Do we have $|L_A| \leq |r_A|$ and $|L_A|=|r_A|$ iff $L_A=r_A$?

This is tested for Nakayama algebras and true for all such algebras with at most 7 simple modules using QPA (it would even be interesting to ask this question only for Nakayama algebras).

I would expect this to be somewhere in the literature at least for acyclic algebras, but this question is also for general algebras including those with a non-acyclic quiver.

(It seems the tits unit form has been considered only for acyclic quiver algebras yet, or is there literature also for general such algebras?)